# Is there any options that I can add a constructor to a class that derives from PSCmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to create a Powershell Cmdlet in C#, and I have some classes with constructors.

But the problem is that when I run command ex. `Add-NewOption` it shows that the command is unknown. Otherwise, when I don't have the constructor it runs perfectly.

So is there any way I can have a constructor in a Cmdlet?

p.s. It's the same for both `Cmdlet` and `PSCmdlet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have a parameterless constructor in a Cmdlet.

As a workaround, you can override `BeginProcessing()` method and use it for initialization tasks. You can access Cmdlet parameters (properties marked as `[Parameter()]`) from inside `BeginProcessing()`. Also, you can override `Dispose()` and `EndProcessing()` methods and perform cleanup there.

Keep in mind, that `EndProcessing()` is not called if either one of `ProcessRecord()` or `BeginProcessing()` throws exception, but `Dispose()` is always gets called at the end of pipeline.

Comment: Ok then. Thank you for your info!

Answer (score 0):

In order to be instantiated by the PowerShell engine, there must be a public parameter-less constructor available. By not writing any constructors in your code, the compiler is adding this by default.
This isn't to say that a cmdlet class can't have other constructors; for unit tests, you might want to include an internal constructor that takes parameters for test dependency injection, but if you include one of these, you must obviously manually add a public parameter-less one because the compiler won't do it for you. I've been bitten by this in the past.